# Tomcat servlet, redirect all urls to a single webpage

Tags: javascript, tomcat, servlets, web-deployment

I deployed a servlet '`csvreports`' in tomcat. '`index.html`' in csvreports picks csv file from `data/` folder and displays as html table.

The url format is

```
localhost:8080/csvreports/?csv=test.csv
```

I am parsing the url in `index.html` to get csv file name and read from `/data/test.csv` in the code.

Now, the url is changed to like `localhost:8080/csvreports/folder1/?csv=test.csv,` 
`localhost:8080/csvreports/folder2/?csv=test.csv` etc.

folder1 and folder2 gets generated dynamically and assuming the folders are already present in `tomcat/webapps/csvreports/`

I need to execute the same `index.html` for all urls. My idea is to parse url to get the path and finally use the path to read csv.

I wanted to how to redirect `localhost:8080/csvreports/*/?csv=test.csv` to a single webpage.

Any other ideas on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: you are trying to get  file path in index.html? What method are you using to get file path in index.html? I think you need to use server side programming to get file path e.g. php or jsp.

Comment: Why don't you put the 'folder1' and 'folder2' part in the `csv` path variable, rather than the url itself? For example: `localhost:8080/csvreports/?csv=folder1/test.csv`

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam, I am using javascript code to get the file path and csv name. Here is the code ` function getCSVPath() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  alert(url);
  var csvfile = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=")+1,url.length);
  alert(url.split('/'));
  return 'data/'+csvfile;
 }`

Comment: @AndrewMairose, I checked and unfortunately we can't modify as the url is being populated by other web application.  [localhost:8080/csvreports/folder1/?csv=test.csv] is the format.

Answer (score 4):

## Mapping all URLs to same page

Use an `index.jsp` instead of an `index.html`. You could literally just rename the file, without changing any of the contents.

Then in your web.xml, you can specify that all URLs starting with `/csvreports` should be routed to your `index.jsp`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/csvreports/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

## Regex for extracting path

In your `index.jsp`, you could use a regex on your URL with two capturing groups.

```
var regex = /.*csvreports\/(.*)\?csv=(.*)/g;
```

The first `.*` will tell it to match any characters before csvreports. This way, it will match no matter what your host name is. For example, currently it is localhost:8080, but if you deploy it to a test or production server, or if someone else hits your web server from another machine, it will be something different.

Next, it matches `csvreports`, which means that after the host name, the URL must contain the exact string `csvreports`.

Next, it looks for a single slash `/`.

Then, comes the first capturing group `(.*)`. The parentheses indicate that it is a matching group. The `.*` tells it to match any character. So, it will match all characters between the first `/` in your URL and the question mark `?`.

Then, it will look for `?csv=`.

And finally, a second capture group `(.*)` is used to capture any characters after the `=`.

---

Now that you have the regex all set to match your URL, you can call the `.exec()` method on the regex, and pass it your URL.

```
var match = regex.exec(url);
```

Finally, you can extract the captured groups from the `match` variable that is returned from the call to `.exec()`.

```
var directories = match[1];
var csvfilename = match[2];
```

You can get your path by concatenating those two matched groups. You may also want to check to ensure that there is a `/` at the end of your `directories`. For example, the regex should match `localhost:8080/csvreports/folder1?csv=file.csv`, but in this case `directories='folder1'` and `csvfilename=file.csv`, so when you concatenate them, you would get `'folder1file.csv'`, when what you want is `'folder1/file.csv'`. So, before you concatenate them, check if the last character in `directories` is a `/`, and if not, put a `/` between `directories` and `csvfilename`.

---

## Example

Here is a simple example to show this regex in action.

```js
function getPathFromUrl() {
  var url = document.getElementById('url').value;

  var regex = /.*csvreports\/(.*)\?csv=(.*)/g;
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  
  var span = document.getElementById('path');
  
  
  var directories = match[1];
  var csvfilename = match[2];
  
  var path = directories;
  
  if (path[path.length-1] !== '/') {
    path += '/'
  }
  
  path += csvfilename;    
  
  span.innerHTML = path;
}
```

```html
<input id="url" type="text" value="localhost:8080/csvreports/folder1/?csv=test.csv" size="50">
<button id="button" onclick="getPathFromUrl()">Get Path</button>
<br><br>
<label for="path"><strong>Path:</strong></label>
<span id="path"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Mairose, This definitely works for me. I can use this path to display csv as html table. I can use this script in say /webapps/csvreports/index.html.  The problem i'm facing is how to map all urls to this index.html. I have to take care in web.xml of this servlet.  I need _localhost:8080/csvreports/folder1/?csv=file.csv_ and _localhost:8080/csvreports/folder2/?csv=file2.csv_ to run index.html which your script gets path and with that i can parse csv and display in table format.

Comment: See my updated answer for how to use a `.jsp` to map all of your `csvreports` URLs to that `.jsp`