# Angular2-Dart PathLocationStrategy

Tags: dart, angular2-dart

Refreshing  angular2 dart  page using HashLocationStrategy works  fine as it opens  the exact  same view.

Refreshing the page  using  PathLocationStrategy  - with tomcat server  configured to  serve index.html  -  works  for  the url  without parameter but does not work  for the  url  with parameter.

localhost:8090/menu1   // refresh  works
localhost:8090/menu2/paramVal    //  does not refresh

tomcat  web.xml   has

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
```

main.dart

```
main() {  
      bootstrap(AppComponent, [  
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS,  
      provide(APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/')]);  
}
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:mboxes/menu1.dart';
import 'package:mboxes/menu2.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: const[ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ])

@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(
      path: '/menu1',
      name: 'Menu1',
      component: Menu1Component,
      useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(
      path: '/menu2/:param', name: 'Menu2', component: Menu2Component)
])
class AppComponent {}
```

app_component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Menu1']">Menu1</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a [routerLink]="['Menu2', {'param':'paramVal'}]">Menu2</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div style="padding-left: 200px; padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 50px">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

menu1.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';
@Component(
    selector: 'menu1',
    template: ''' menu 1 was clicked '''
)
class Menu1Component {}
```

menu2.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';
@Component(
    selector: 'menu2',
    template: ''' menu 2 was clicked'''
)
class Menu2Component implements OnInit {
  final RouteParams _routeParams;
  Menu2Component(this._routeParams);
  ngOnInit()  {
    var val  = _routeParams.get('param');
    print  ("passed param is " +  val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the application served at the root folder or is `heros` a detail folder. Normally there is nothing else to do than configuring `PathLocationStrategy` (default) and rewrite requests to non-existing URLs to `index.html`.

Comment: I have only two  folders - web folder contains index.html  and  lib folder contains all other components

Comment: Application is being served from  the root  folder.  URLs  with parameter do not refresh.  URLs without parameter   refresh  fine.

Comment: Can you update the question to make it more clear what error you see? What does it mean when it "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `404` to serve index.html I think you want to set up a `servlet-mapping` with something like `<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>`

See also [Tomcat servlet, redirect all urls to a single webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678276/tomcat-servlet-redirect-all-urls-to-a-single-webpage/33681259#33681259)