# Refresh issue after deploy angular2 project into tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, angular2-routing

After production build I have deployed project in to tomcat server. When i open it in browser it is opening perfect and routing also working. But when I refresh the browser showing error 404. My tomcat folder structures is below

```
build path
tomcat
  --webapps
     --prod
           --assets
           --css
           --js
           index.html
```

http://localhost:8080/prod/

**seed.config.ts**

```
APP_BASE = argv['base'] || '/';
```

**index.html**

```
<base href="/prod/">
```

This problem iam facing only on refresh the page. Please anyone help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using HTML5 routing (without the #) so you need some server config in order for all the requests (minus the files and folders) to be routed to the index.html. Something like the below in an .htaccess file of the root folder should fix it :-

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Edit:-
The above is for an Apache server, when it comes to a Tomcat server the same applies - you need to redirect all traffic to your index.html file. I could write it out but [Andrew Mairose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678276/tomcat-servlet-redirect-all-urls-to-a-single-webpage) details how to do this and so no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I have written .htaccess file also. **sample.htaccess** `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]`  How to use this htaccess file please explain

Comment: Hello, updated my answer as .htaccess won't work on a Tomcat server - apologies.

Comment: How to resolve this issue. Please anyone help me on this.